# Differences between Greenrobot EventBus and Guava's EventBus

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I´ve been using quite often EventBus from greenrobot

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

But I´ve just realised that Guava has its own EventBus

[com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/package-summary.html)

Does someone know if there are big differences?

Comment: Just to be clear, com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus is not a part of Android. It's from Guava, a set of Java libraries mostly developed by Google. So both of these are extra libraries you'd have to include in your app.

Comment: Agree with that. are there big differences between one or another? which one is preferible to use?

Comment: I've only used the greenrobot version so I'm not sure, sorry!

Comment: Me too, that´s why I was wondering if it was worth to use the Google one, although so far the Greenboot works perfectly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both are excellent quality library.

Here is a [comparison](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/COMPARISON.md) (from greenrobot developpers point of view) between greenrobot `EventBus` and `Otto` (a fork from `Guava` specialized for android).

I personnaly like `EventBus` because it support delivery in background threads

Answer (score 8):

No more need to compare where [otto](https://github.com/square/otto) is deprecated and writes a note:

This project is deprecated in favor of RxJava and [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid).

Answer (score 2):

EventBus can do some Android specific tricks, which other implementations don't support. First, there is main thread support to conveniently switch threads.Second its performance was optimized especially for Android. For example, with EventBus 3 you get annotations without the performance downgrade you would have with Otto or Guava.

Answer (score 0):

**Otto** is deprecated in favor of RxJava and RxAndroid.

**RxJava** 1.x is **end-of-life** as of **March 31, 2018**.

Use [RxJava 2.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), I guess.